# Implementing a compass with HereAPI Android SDK Explore Edition

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to rotate an ImageView based on the PinchRotateListener's updates using HereAPI Explore for Android

```
class CompassView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    private var currentDegree = 0.0
    
    fun rotate(degree: Double) {
        var rotationFrom = currentDegree
        var rotationTo = degree

        // correct rotation angles
        if (rotationFrom < -180) {
            rotationFrom += 360
        }
        while (rotationTo - rotationFrom < -180) {
            rotationTo += 360
        }
        while (rotationTo - rotationFrom > 180) {
            rotationTo -= 360
        }

        val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree.toFloat(),
            rotationTo.toFloat(),
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f
        )

        rotateAnimation.duration = 210
        rotateAnimation.fillAfter = true
        this.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)

        currentDegree = rotationTo
    }
}
```

the degree I am getting from the PinchRotateListener, which I am passing to my own listener and calling .rotate() afterwards:

```
 map_view.gestures.setPinchRotateListener { gestureState, point2D, point2D2, d, angle ->
            if (gestureState == GestureState.UPDATE) {
                listener.invoke(angle.degrees)
            }
        }
```

However the value returned is some weird float, and there is no way to get the actual value or am I missing something? Is there a better way to get the new orientation in degrees? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I get the bearing the following way:

```
map_view.gestures.setPinchRotateListener { gestureState, point2D, point2D2, d, angle ->
            if (gestureState == GestureState.UPDATE) {
                listener.invoke(camera.state.targetOrientation.bearing)
        
            }
        }
```

where `camera` is `MapCamera`

So its `camera.state.targetOrientation.bearing` instead of `angle.degrees`